# VFP Find records which also exist in another table

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I want to find records from a customer table where there is an invoice in the current period (Table Dayb).  I have this code copied from another program, but - in my ignorance - may be making heavy weather of it and using the wrong construct.

```
SELECT Account, Common_name FROM Customer;
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Account FROM DayB WHERE DayB.Account = Cust.Account) ;
   INTO CURSOR T1
```

Grateful for suggestions;  and can you recommend a simple guide to SQL.

Thanks.  Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I think you got it ALMOST right with the copied SQL statement.

```
SELECT Account, Common_name FROM Customer ;
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DayB WHERE DayB.Account = Customer.Account) ;
   INTO CURSOR T1 ;
   NOFILTER
```

Here, you are selecting 2 fields from customer (Account and Common_Name). Where part checks if those customer records EXISTS in DayB too, depending on common field Account. Cust.Account would be right, if you also aliased Customer as cust. ie:

```
SELECT Account, Common_name FROM Customer Cust;
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DayB WHERE DayB.Account = Cust.Account) ;
   INTO CURSOR T1 ;
   NOFILTER
```

This aliasing is done often, to give shorter aliases to cursors.

In EXISTS check it is not important what you select, it could be Select Account, Select * or even a constant like Select 1. Whatever in there, it is not selected anyway, an EXISTS clauses merely checks only for existence and returns a boolean.

Finally we added NOFILTER there as rule of thumb to prevent filtering of rows and creating what is called a "true cursor".

Now, a little more primer. When you need to check for rows that also exists in another table, there are basically 3 SQL constructs to do that.

EXISTS check as in the above.

Using an IN clause:

```
   SELECT Account, Common_name FROM Customer ;
       WHERE Account in (SELECT Account FROM DayB) ;
       INTO CURSOR T1 ;
       NOFILTER
```

And INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Customer.Account, Customer.Common_name FROM Customer ;
   INNER JOIN DayB ON DayB.Account = Customer.Account ;
   INTO CURSOR T1 ;
   NOFILTER
```

The last one, however, would repeat each row from Customer as many times as there is match in DayB. That one is used often when you also need fields from DayB too.

Performance wise, EXISTS is probably the best one of these.

Comment: I like this answer, I wonder if "set exact on" should be set to true for best results?

Comment: @Hank, set exact has no effect in SQL statements. To get the effect of set exact ON, you need to set set ANSI ON. Regardless of set ANSI setting, an exact match can be obtained by the operator == (instead of =).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Cetin  -  sorry, had been away.

Your notes are very useful.  In the matter of aliases, I certainly use them.  But the sample was so short that it perhaps scarcely needed  it!

I will experiment further with INNER JOIN – hoping it is perhaps the simplest of the many JOINs

Have appreciated your guidance